# Format float to 3 significant figures after decimal point

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would you format a float to three signicant figures after a decimal place? If the float has no decimal places then the number should remain the same.

This is correct:

```
'{0:.3}'.format(0.000325658)
'0.000326'
```

This is incorrect:

```
'{0:.3}'.format(325256.023)
'3.25e+05'
```

and should be

```
325256.023
```

The value `325256.0` should be output as `325256.0`.

I'd like this to be done with a single `''.format()` if possible.

Test cases:

```
0.000325658 - > 0.000326
325256.023 - > 325256.023
325256.0 - > 325256.0 or 325256.000
```

Edit add new test case:

```
'{0:.3f}'.format(325256.000023)
'325256.000'
```

should be

```
325256.000023
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're happy to include numpy then you could use the [numpy.format_float_positional](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.format_float_positional.html) function, with an extra step:

```py
import numpy as np

def to_significant_decimals(n, amount):
    integer = int(n)
    n -= integer
    return integer + float(np.format_float_positional(n, precision=amount, unique=False, fractional=False))

tests = [ 0.000325658, 325256.023, 325256.0, 325256.000023, 0, 7, 1000000, 1000.3, 1000.0001, 1234.4321 ]
for test in tests:
    print(' ' + str(test) + ' =  ' + str(to_significant_decimals(test, 3)))
    print(str(-test) + ' = ' + str(to_significant_decimals(-test, 3)))
```

The numpy function allows you to choose the amount of significant figures, but this includes the integer part. I've solved that by taking the integer part away, doing the format, then adding the integer back on. There's probably a more elegant solution, but this gives the results that you want.

Outputs:

```
 0.000325658 =  0.000326
-0.000325658 = -0.000326
 325256.023 =  325256.023
-325256.023 = -325256.023
 325256.0 =  325256.0
-325256.0 = -325256.0
 325256.000023 =  325256.000023
-325256.000023 = -325256.000023
 0 =  0.0
 0 =  0.0
 7 =  7.0
-7 = -7.0
 1000000 =  1000000.0
-1000000 = -1000000.0
 1000.3 =  1000.3
-1000.3 = -1000.3
 1000.0001 =  1000.0001
-1000.0001 = -1000.0001
 1234.4321 =  1234.432
-1234.4321 = -1234.432
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like that

```
'{0:.3f}'.format(325256.023)
```

Comment: Use if statment

Comment: I'd rather use a single format if possible